# JayData cannot initialize context

Tags: javascript, jaydata

I tried to use JayData based on the following [tutorial](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-build-a-simple-odata-based-ajax-application-with-visual-studio-2010).
I created my JS file with JaySVCUtil and the context is the following:

```
$data.EntityContext.extend('MyCtx.MyContext', {
    'DataTable1': { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType:MyCtx.DataTable1}
});
```

I have the following scripts included:

```
<script src="Scripts/datajs-1.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jaydata.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jaydata-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jaydataproviders/oDataProvider.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/MyCtx.js"></script>
```

I try to use it in my webpage:

```
function db () {
    alert("test1");
    var mongo = new MyCtx.MyContext({ name: 'oData', oDataServiceHost: 'http://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/MongoDataService.svc' });
    alert("test2");
}
```

The first alert is shown then I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: MyCtx is not defined

If I modify to

```
new MyContext(...)
```

then the error is the following:

> ReferenceError: MyContext is not defined

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the JS files are loaded **asynchronously** so the JS file containing the context class has not been loaded yet when it was referenced (loading should consider references, though).

After a *few swaps of the loaded `<script>` lines*, it has been resolved.